# Mongodb Pymongo remove fields from documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My idea is to remove certain data updated earlier on certain conditions. For that I cant update documents with any null/None value. That should not going to happen in Mongodb. As a workaround, I am got to use `$unset` in MonngoDB. The docs says, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) that we can pop a field from a document using `$unset`. like this

```
db.collections.update({ id: uid }, { $unset: [ "<field1>", "<field2>", ... ] })
```

My question is this. How can we achieve this with Pymongo.?

Comment: You can issue $unset etc. in all drivers including pymongo.

Comment: @D.SM, thats not working there is some difference in symbols

Comment: Add what you have done and what the results were to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo is generally similar to the mongodb shell commands, but it has to work within the constraints of the python syntax. Importantly, you must put the `$` operators in quotes, so `"$unset"` as per below.

db.collections.update_one({ "id": uid }, { "$unset": [ "", "", ... ] })

If this doesn't work, post the error you are getting.